# Regular Expression: L= {w | every even position of w is '1'}

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to solve a regular expression of binary string where every even position is a '1'

I've solved this for an **odd position**: (1(0+1))*(1+ε)

How would it look like for an even position then? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You successfully solved the odd position case. What makes the even position case conceptually more difficult?

Comment: I was a bit confused though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd position can either have 0 or 1 and every even position can only have 1. RE for this can be: $$ ((0 + 1)1)^* (\epsilon + (0+1))$$ Note that, it also contains the empty word.

Comment: you are missing words of odd length

Comment: added the edit, thanks for pointing it out.